# How to use a header only library in C++ using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to use a header-only library in my project.

In my folder */home/user/Desktop/tutorial*, I have a folder *websocketpp*, which is copied from https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/tree/master/websocketpp.

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "websocketpp/config/asio_client.hpp"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello\n";
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(tutorial VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

include_directories(websocketpp)

add_executable(tutorial main.cpp)
```

When I do this, I get this error:

```
[main] Building folder: Tutorial all
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --build /home/user/Desktop/tutorial/build --config Debug --target all -j 6 --
[build] [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/tutorial.dir/main.cpp.o
[build] In file included from /home/user/Desktop/tutorial/main.cpp:2:
[build] /home/user/Desktop/tutorial/websocketpp/config/asio_client.hpp:31:10: fatal error: websocketpp/config/core_client.hpp: No such file or directory
[build]    31 | #include <websocketpp/config/core_client.hpp>
[build]       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] compilation terminated.
[build] gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/tutorial.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/tutorial.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
[build] gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:839: CMakeFiles/tutorial.dir/all] Error 2
[build] gmake: *** [Makefile:121: all] Error 2
[proc] The command: /usr/bin/cmake --build /home/user/Desktop/tutorial/build --config Debug --target all -j 6 -- exited with code: 2
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:00.179
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

I have tried to use < instead of ", various includes etc. but it does not seem to work. In my tutorial folder I have /websocketpp, main.cpp and CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Offtopic: `include_directories` is legacy API and should not be used in modern cmake.

Comment: Just as offtopic: CMake version 3.0.0 and language `C` for an obvious C++ only project? Slow down on the copy-pasting. Websocketpp comes with a CMakeLists.txt so rather use theirs and `target_link_libraries(tutorial websocketpp)`

Comment: `include_directories()` is either deprecated or discouraged (or both - I'm not sure which offhand) with modern cmake.     In modern cmake, it is preferable to use `target_include_directories()`.   From documentation, that requires a named target that has been previously created (e.g. with `add_executable` or `add_library()`).   Refer to https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html

Answer (score 2):

You should go like this:

Dir structure:

```
+ dependency
   + websocketpp -  https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/tree/master/websocketpp
   CMakeLists.txt
+ src
   main.cpp
   CMakeLists.txt
CMakeLists.txt
```

And organize CMake more or less like this.

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(tutorial VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_subdirectory(dependency)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

`dependency/CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_libarary(websocketpp INTERAFACE)
target_include_directories(websocketpp INTERAFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR});
```

`src/CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_executable(tutorial main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tutorial PUBLIC websocketpp)
```

`src/main.cpp`

```
#include <websocketpp/config/asio_client.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: How do i now include the file in main.cpp

Comment: I did update. Note change in `target_include_directories`

Answer (score 1):

Consider using

```
target_include_directories(tutorial PUBLIC "websocketpp")
```

this specifies the include directory just for the target `tutorial` instead of the whole CMake project.
However there seems to be a `CMakeLists.txt` in websocketpp (root directory not the one containing config). This allows you to include websocket into your CMake project via the command

```
add_subdirectory(websocketpp)
```

and then in `main.cpp`

```
#include "websocketpp/websocketpp/config/asio_client.hpp"
```

note the double `websocketpp`.

(Note that both ways requires the whole git to be cloned and not just the one nested websocketpp folder, otherwise the first "websocketpp" in each `#include` needs to be dropped)